# Spark Facade for CaseWhen

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to make a function that acts like a Facade for `CaseWhen` spark function.

```
CaseWhen(
    branches: Seq[(Expression, Expression)],
    elseValue: Option[Expression] = None): ...
```

So, `CaseWhen` takes a Seq of `(Expression, Expression)`, the first `Expression` is the condition and the second is the value. It also take an `Option[Expression]` for the else value.

Basically, I want to give a nested `Map[Column, Column]` object with the first `Column` being the condition and the second the value to put if this condition is satisfied.

I managed to do it for the most simple use case : Having only one level of `(Condition, Value)`. Here's my code :

```
def withExpr(expr: Expression): Column = new Column(expr)

def caseWhenFacade(
       outputColName: String,
       conditionsValues: Map[Column, Column],
       defaultValue: Option[Column] = None
)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    require(conditionsValues.nonEmpty, "Cannot call caseWhenFacadewith an Empty Map")

    val conditionalMap =  conditionsValues.map(x => (x._1.expr, x._2.expr)).toSeq

    defaultValue match {
      case Some(value) => df.withColumn(
        colName,
        withExpr {CaseWhen(
            conditionalMap,
            value.expr
            )}
      )
      case None => df.withColumn(
        colName,
        withExpr {CaseWhen(
          conditionalMap
          )}
      )
  }
  }
```

Here's how i use that function:

```
val spec = Map(
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> lit(2),
    ($"column_one" === 2 && $"column_two" === 1) -> lit(1),
    ($"column_one" === 3) -> lit(4),
)
df.transform(caseWhenFacade("column_three", spec))
```

This works great, but Now, I want to give this spec Map :

```
val spec: Map[Column, Any] = Map(
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> Map(
        ($"column_two" === 2) -> lit(54),
        ($"column_two" === 5) -> lit(524)
    ),
    ($"column_one" === 2) -> Map(
        ($"column_two" === 7) -> Map(
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever") -> lit(12),
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever_two") -> lit(13)
        ),
        ($"column_two" === 8) -> lit(524)
    ),
    ($"column_one" === 3) -> lit(4)
)
```

And this obviously, doesn't work with my `caseWhenFacade` function. And I can't really figure out a way to do this.

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's because (as you know), an instance of `Map[Column, Any]` is not an instance of spark's `Column`. I can think of two approaches to this, one of them is an unsafe approach, which I'm not going to explain deeply, but to give you some idea about it, you can use `conditionsValues: Map[Column, Any]` in your `caseWhenFacade`, and try to inline the conditions into a single `Map[Column, Column]` using `&&` on the keys. Another approach which I would recommend, is very similar to the first approach, but it is safe. You can make an ADT representing what your conditions and values look like:

```scala
sealed trait ConditionValue {
  def enumerate(conditionReduce: (Column, Column) => Column): List[(Column, Column)]
}

case class SingleConditionValue(condition: Column, value: Column) extends ConditionValue {
  override def enumerate(conditionReduce: (Column, Column) => Column): List[(Column, Column)] = 
    (condition -> value) :: Nil
}

case class NestedConditionValue(conditions: Map[Column, ConditionValue]) extends ConditionValue {
  def enumerate(conditionReduce: (Column, Column) => Column): List[(Column, Column)] = 
    conditions.mapValues(_.enumerate(conditionReduce)).map {
      case (outerCondition, innerExpressions) => 
        innerExpressions.map { case (innerCondition, innerValue) => 
          conditionReduce((outerCondition, innerCondition)) -> innerValue
        }
    }
}
```

Just to take a quick look at what this modeling means, in your nested Map object, which looks like this:

```scala
val spec: Map[Column, Any] = Map(
  ($"column_one" === 1) -> Map(
      ($"column_two" === 2) -> lit(54),
      ($"column_two" === 5) -> lit(524)
  )
)
```

Another way to express this map would be this:

```scala
val spec: Map[Column, Column] = Map(
  (($"column_one" === 1) && ($"column_two" === 2)) -> lit(54),
  (($"column_one" === 1) && ($"column_two" === 2)) -> lit(524)
)
```

Right? As you can see, we are reducing to conditions, using `&&`. So this is exactly what `conditionReduce` is meant to do in the `enumerate` method. And what I mean by reducing, is the reduction of that outer nested map into a single map, where nested conditions are reduced into one. At the end, your code would look something like this:

```scala
def caseWhenFacade(
  outputColName: String,
  conditionsValues: ConditionValue,
  defaultValue: Option[Column] = None
)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  require(conditionsValues.nonEmpty, "Cannot call caseWhenFacadewith an Empty Map")

  // this can be defined globally
  val and: (Column, Column) => Column = _ && _

  val conditionalMap: List[(Column, Column)] = conditionsValues.enumerate(and) // this meand do the 'and' operation on conditions

  defaultValue match {
    case Some(value) => 
      df.withColumn(
        colName,
        withExpr {CaseWhen(
          conditionalMap,
          value.expr
          )}
      )
    case None => 
      df.withColumn(
        colName,
        withExpr {CaseWhen(
          conditionalMap
        )}
      )
  }
}
```

One more thing to mention, which is obvious, is that you need to wrap your conditions and values, into instances of this ADT, or you can use implicit conversion to make the usage easier.

Comment: You're a monster haha I've tought about the first approach but didn't tried it because of the `Any` type. That's a pretty neat way of using ADTs. Thanks alot !

Comment: Quick question about the implicits that I've to define for `NestedConditionValue`. As I'm trying to implement these, I feel that I'll need to define an implicit for every level of Map. Like one for `Map[Column, Map[Column, Column]`, one for `Map[Column, Map[Column, Map[Column, Column]]`, etc.

Is there a way to define a single implicit for `NestedConditionValue` that can handle any level ? If yes, I can make a new question and mention you on it.

Comment: No you don't need to define an implicit conversion for every possibility of nested Map. Actually, I'm looking at my answer again, and I found out that it's better to define `SingleConditionValue` as this: `case class SingleConditionValue(value: Column) extends ...`. Now you would need two methods: first `implicit def makeCond(raw: Column): ConditionValue = SingleConditionValue(raw)`. Another one would be `implicit def makeMapHolder(raw: Map[Column, SingleConditionValue]): SingleConditionValue = MapHolder(raw)`.

Comment: One more important thing to note is that you need to explicitly declare the generic type of the Maps in your code, when you want to use these implicit conversions: `val myConds: ConditionValue = Map[Column, ConditionValue](cond1 -> Map[Column, ConditionValue](cond2 -> value2))`.

Comment: I can't really understand how making SingleConditionValue take only one column is helpful :/ I'll make a new question and mention you on it.

Comment: New question created : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74574179/spark-casewhen-as-map-with-adts

Comment: Oh I see, you just convert it into a Map. Okay, I'll take a look at the question RN

Comment: Yeah I think it's simpler to convert a Map to a Seq of (Expression Expression). Anyway, don't do by my solution, I find your approach to problems really interesting and I'm learning alot from your answers, just do as you would normally do.

Comment: Actually, if you make `SingleConditionValue` hold only a `Column`, you can fix this easily. I'm thinking if we can solve it this way.