# Spark CaseWhen as Map with ADTs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, algebraic-data-types

This question is a follow-up for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74461147/spark-facade-for-casewhen).

Quick context reminder :

Spark's `CaseWhen` takes a `Seq[(Expression, Expression)]` with the first Expression being the condition and the second, the value to put if this condition is satisfied :

```
CaseWhen(
    branches: Seq[(Expression, Expression)],
    elseValue: Option[Expression] = None): ...
```

I want to be able to do Spark's CaseWhen using a Map object.

The Map can be simple such as :

```
val spec = Map(
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> lit(2),
    ($"column_one" === 2 && $"column_two" === 1) -> lit(1),
    ($"column_one" === 3) -> lit(4),
)
```

It also can be nested and simple at the same time:

```
val spec: Map[Column, Any] = Map(
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> Map(
        ($"column_two" === 2) -> lit(54),
        ($"column_two" === 5) -> lit(524)
    ),
    ($"column_one" === 2) -> Map(
        ($"column_two" === 7) -> Map(
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever") -> lit(12),
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever_two") -> lit(13)
        ),
        ($"column_two" === 8) -> lit(524)
    ),
    ($"column_one" === 3) -> lit(4)
)
```

So, using the answer given by @aminmal on the other question I made this :

```
sealed trait ConditionValue  {
  def enumerate(reduceFunc: (Column, Column) => Column): Seq[(Expression, Expression)]
}
object ConditionValue {

  object implicits{

    implicit def test(condition: Column, value: Column): ConditionValue = {
        print("test")
        SingleLevelCaseWhen(Map(condition -> value))
        
    }
    
    implicit def testTuple(conditionValue: (Column, Column)): ConditionValue = {
        print("testTuple")
        SingleLevelCaseWhen(Map(conditionValue))
        
    }
        
    implicit def testNested(spec: Map[Column, ConditionValue]): ConditionValue = {
        print("testNested")
        NestedCaseWhen(spec)
        
    }
        
    implicit def testMap(spec: Map[Column, Column]): ConditionValue = {
        print("testMap")
        SingleLevelCaseWhen(spec)
        
    }
    
    implicit def expressionToColumn(expr: Expression): Column = new Column(expr)

    implicit def columnToExpression(col: Column): Expression = col.expr
  }
    
  import implicits._

  final case class SingleLevelCaseWhen(specificationMap: Map[Column, Column]) extends ConditionValue{
    override def enumerate(reduceFunc: (Column, Column) => Column): Seq[(Expression, Expression)] =
      specificationMap.map(x => (x._1.expr, x._2.expr)).toSeq
  }
  
  final case class NestedCaseWhen(specificationMap: Map[Column, ConditionValue]) extends ConditionValue{
    override def enumerate(reduceFunc: (Column, Column) => Column): Seq[(Expression, Expression)] =
      specificationMap.mapValues(_.enumerate(reduceFunc)).map{
        case (outerCondition, innerExpressions) => innerExpressions.map{
          case (innerCondition, innerValue) =>
            val conditions: Expression = reduceFunc(outerCondition, innerCondition)
            conditions -> innerValue

        }
      }.reduce(_ ++ _)
  }

}
```

My problem now, is how to convert `Map` objects to `ConditionValue` Objects. As you can see, I've provided on the code some implicits :

- `test` converts a `condition, value` params to a `ConditionValue` object. Not sure this one is useful
- `testTuple` converts a `(condition, value)` tuple params to a `ConditionValue` object. Not sure this one is useful either
- `testMap`  converts a single-level `Map[Column, Column]` to a `ConditionValue` object
- `testNested` converts a nested Map to a `ConditionValue` object

It works great with single-level Maps :

```
import ConditionValue.implicits._
val spec = Map(
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> lit(2),
    ($"column_one" === 2 && $"column_two" === 1) -> lit(1),
    ($"column_one" === 3) -> lit(4)
)
val d: ConditionValue= spec
>> d: ConditionValue= SingleLevelCaseWhen(Map((column_one = 1) -> 2, ((column_one = 2) AND (column_two = 1)) -> 1, (column_one = 3) -> 4))
```

Also, it works with nested only Map :

```
val spec = Map[Column, ConditionValue](
    ($"column_one" === 1) -> Map(
        ($"column_two" === 2) -> lit(54),
        ($"column_two" === 5) -> lit(524)
    ),
    ($"column_one" === 2) -> Map[Column, ConditionValue](
        ($"column_two" === 7) -> Map(
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever") -> lit(12),
            ($"whatever_column" === "whatever_two") -> lit(13)
        )
    )
)
val d: ConditionValue= spec
>>d: ConditionValue= NestedCaseWhen(Map((column_one = 1) -> SingleLevelCaseWhen(Map((column_two = 2) -> 54, (column_two = 5) -> 524)), (column_one = 2) -> NestedCaseWhen(Map((column_two = 7) -> SingleLevelCaseWhen(Map((whatever_column = whatever) -> 12, (whatever_column = whatever_two) -> 13))))))
```

There's two things bothering me right now :

- It doesn't work with mixed Maps (Nested and Simple in the same time)
- When dealing with Nested Maps, I have to explicitly specify the type of the Map `Map[Column, ConditionValue]`

Can anyone help me up with that ?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

I kinda "fixed" the `It doesn't work with mixed Maps (Nested and Simple in the same time)` problem with this implicits :

```
implicit def testVal(value: Column): ConditionValue = {
        testMap(Map(lit(true) -> value))
    }
```

Not sure If it's the best possible solution.

Comment: Can you also post an example of how you create `mixed Maps (Nested and Simple in the same time)` objects?

Comment: Basically, it's a `Map[Column, Any]`, I've posted an example under :
>It also can be nested and simple at the same time.
(Take a look at the second code-block on the question)